# Not able to insert image in database mysql from other page

Tags: php, sql, image

i am trying to insert image from other webpage into local database
This are example of page source that i have extracted

```
<html>
    ...
    <div class=story-box>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/assets/images/CM.gif">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>yuoyuouoyuoyuyu oyuiouioyuioyuyiouyoiy youyoiyuioyuioyuyoiuyiuyiyuioyu yuyiu</p>
    </div>
    ...
    </html>
```

i can insert heading and article section in database but not get that image of  `<img src="http://www.example.com/assets/images/CM.gif">`

i use below php code to insert

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = 'http://www.example.com';
    $html1=file_get_html($url);
    $heading=$html1->find("div.story-box h2",0);
    $heading1=strip_tags($heading);
    echo $heading;

    $image=$html1->find("div.story-box img",0);
    $image1=strip_tags($image);
    echo $image;
    $content = '';
    foreach($html1->find('div.story-box p') as $e)
    {
    $content.=$e;
    $content1=strip_tags($content);
    }
    echo $content
 ?>
```

below code are the process of inserting to db

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(! $connect )
            {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("test1");

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO test '.
       '(heading, image, article) '.
       'VALUES ("'. mysql_real_escape_string($heading1) . '", "'.    mysql_real_escape_string($image1) . '", "'. mysql_real_escape_string($content1). '")';

        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connect );
        if(! $retval )
        {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        mysql_close($connect);
    }
    ?>
```

these are sql statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `heading` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  `article` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

when after successful insertion image field if mysql database  only get this [BLOB - 0 B], not actual image. please suggest someone to extract real image and to insert in database

Comment: Is your echo $image working ? What does it echo ?

Comment: it just to show image of that webpage into my browser after running php file

Comment: I wanted to know if it was working because strip_tags should by definition make $image empty by stripping the img tag along with src

Comment: now ok after removing strip_tags i can insert image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strip_tags` on `<img src="http://www.example.com/assets/images/CM.gif">` will remove the entire tag. You should use a regex to extract the URL of the image from the tag instead:

```
$image = $html1->find("div.story-box img",0);
// empty array to store result
$img_arr = array();
// extract the src form the img tag
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $image, $img_arr ) ;
// save src
$image1 =  $img_arr[1];
// insert into db
```

Comment: Thank you Niraj Shah, after removing that strip_tags i can insert image getting this in my db image field '[BLOB - 71 B] ', but when i try to extract it from db again it show no image.

Comment: Change the type to VARCHAR. You don't need to save it as a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
$image=$html1->find("div.story-box img",0);
$image1=strip_tags($image);
echo $image;
```

Strip tags removes all html and php tags and does not return src attribute of image. You should extract the src of the img tag instead and add it to database